# MS project status update with % complete AND actual work

Tags: ms-project, software-development, planning

I have created a new MS Project project with a task in it. This task has a "Work" of 360 hours and is assigned to two resources. The task is scheduled with "Fixed units" and "Effort-driven" options, since the duration should automatically decrease when adding more resources - it is a software development task. The start date of the task is June 16, 2023. I have created a baseline for it in Project.

Now, I want to update the project. To do this, I have entered the status date as July 25, 2023, under Project => Status Date. At this point, the task has a completion percentage of 38% and an actual work of 184.25 hours. I want to record this data in MS Project and have MS Project automatically update and forecast the completion date based on this information.

When I enter 38% completion as "% complete," the actual work is automatically set with incorrect value, and "% work complete" is set to 44%. Therefore, I want to enter both the completion percentage and the actual work manually. I am missing the understanding of how this can be configured, even though it is such a common use case.

My goal is to have the planned end date automatically adjusted according to the current situation, and I want to generate an Earned Value Analysis for this project status date.

How can this be achieved?